# Security Patch Supee 9767

Tags: patches, magento-1.9.2.1, supee-9767

Got this error

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
Done
```

Need help on this.

Comment: Shall i know this issue is resolved?

Comment: i am getting this issue in magento 1.9.3.1

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that **you deleted or renamed the original `app/design/frontend/rwd/default` theme.**

I reckon you should ensure that folder is here.

If it's not there, **I suggest you download a fresh copy of your Magento version and copy that folder over.**

If it's there, **it could be a permission issue so I suggest you double check that too.**

Comment: Hi Raphael, Is it necessary to put that folder? In addition I used putty, do you know how this command would work Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  ** Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored **

Comment: @JmCabugnason that folder is necessary to apply the patch yeah even if you don't use it. Alternatively you can modify the patch file to remove the reference to those files but I suggest not to. Right now you don't need to reverse because the patch hasn't been applied yet

Comment: I added the folder but still it throw this error **Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

Comment: @JmCabugnason could you edit your question and add the full log you're getting when you run the patch please

Comment: Hi Raphael here is the full log Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.

Comment: Hi Raphael here is the full log Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  
Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/multishipping/billing.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n] 
Skipping patch.

Do you know how to run this command on putty 
Assume -R? [n] 
Apply anyway? [n]

Comment: @JmCabugnason please edit your question and add that info to it.

Comment: Hi Raphael
Got his error after added the rwd folder

Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
Done

Hope you can help me on this.